# Kotlin: Idomatic way to get items from list after a given index

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

Supposed I have a list that has 30 items and the given index is 9, I need to get the items starting index 10 to 19.

Currently doing it in a Java style.

```
                val newsList: ArrayList<Model> = arrayListOf()

                    // Get all items starting next to the current selected item
                    for (i in (position + 1) until originalList.size) {

                        // Limit the amount of item to avoid any possible OOM
                        if (newsList.size < 10)
                            newsList.add(list[i])

                    }
```

Comment: Another way is: val newsList = originalList.drop(position)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`drop`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/drop.html) and [`take`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/take.html) for this kind of thing

```
val items = List(30) { i -> "Item ${i+1}"}
items.drop(10).take(10).run(::println)

>> [Item 11, Item 12, Item 13, Item 14, Item 15, Item 16, Item 17, Item 18, Item 19, Item 20]
```

Also you don't need to worry about how many items are in the collection - if you did `drop(69)` you'd just end up with an empty list. If you did `listOf(1, 2).take(3)` you'd just get `[1, 2]`. They work like "drop/take at most" - you'll only get an error if you use a negative count

Comment: or `items.slice(10 until 20)`